# prevent replacing "&reg" to '®' in query string

Tags: html

I have a hyperlink with some query strings in below format:

```
<a href="site.com?param=1&reg=2">Hyperlink</a>
```

but browser parses it as:

```
<a href="site.com?param=1®=2">Hyperlink</a>
```

How I can prevent this?

Comment: Escape the `&`: `&amp;reg=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By properly encoding the URL since it appears inside HTML:

```
site.com?param=1&amp;reg=2
```

Comment: *attribute* is irrelevant, it is inside HTML.

Comment: @Quentin: Sure, although the correction is IMHO kind of overdoing it.